# ZF2 How to get the translation in my Model (Propel)

Tags: php, zend-framework2, propel, service-locator

In my ZF2 project I'm using Propel as a Model. I'm trying to get my translator in my Category Model. But for some reason I can not get it to work.

I tried to set it via a factory in my module.php which works for plugins etc. But I'm not accessing this model via the controller instead i'm chaining it from another model in the view.

Hope someone can help.

Comment: "i'm chaining it from another model in the view"
Could you explain this statement ?

Comment: In my view I have a collection of users, which in their turn get a list of their acrticles, which reside in one or more categories which must be translated.
$user->getArticle()->getCategories(); And then loop through them as category, $category->getTitletranlated();

Comment: Temporary workaround: Defined a constant with locale in application module.php which i then use to get the correct translation in the category model.

Comment: You are doing it wrong Peter. I don't think your model should use any translations at all since it's the view's responsibility.

Comment: No, the translated strings for the categories are stored in the Db so its definitely the models responsibility